# regex python - using lookbehinds to find my specific text

Tags: python, regex

UPDATED

I want to find a string within a big text

```
 ..."img good img two_apple.txt"
```

Want to extract the two_apples.txt from a text, but it can change to one_apple, three_apple..so on...
When I try to use lookbehinds, it matches text all the way from the beginning.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to parse some sort of HTML/XML/`<>` tag based document with regex. Do not do so. It is a bad idea. use a parser.

Comment: I can use a parser and have done it already, but I want to know how to do it using regex  as practice for a simple case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mis-using lookarounds. Looks like you dont even NEED a lookaround:

```
pattern = r'src="images/(.+?.png")'
```

should work for you. As my comment suggests though, using regex is not recommended for parsing HTML/XML style documents but you do you.

EDIT - accommodate your edit:

Now that I understand your problem more, I can see why you would want to use a look-around. However, since you are looking for a file name, you know there aren't going to be any spaces in the name, so you can just ensure that your capturing token does not include spaces:

```
pattern = r'src="img (\w+?.png")'
                    ^ ensure there is a space HERE because of how your text is
                      \w - \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_] (any letters, numbers or underscore)
```

This removes the greediness of capture the first `'img '` string that pops up and ensures your capture group doesnt have any spaces.

by using `\w`, I am assuming you are only expecting `_` and letter characters. to include anything else, make your own character group with `[any characters you want to capture in here]`

Comment: it still matched 'src=images' before the desired one. Was thinking that a lookaround can help to get the closest one.

Comment: what do you mean "desired one"? your example only shows one.

Comment: I updated the question to be non html tags. If I use this regex 'img.*?apple.txt'.  It matches the first img instead of starting with the second which is desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
" ([^ ]+_apple\.txt)"
```

Starts with a space, ends with _apple.txt. The middle bit is anything-except-a-space which stops it matching "good img two". Parentheses to capture the bit you care about.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/wO7lG3/2